# Finding the $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y+y^2x}{x^3-xy+y^3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the limit (if it exists) of the following function of two variables:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y+y^2x}{x^3-xy+y^3}$$
So far I tried to prove that it doesn't exist by finding two sequences $(x_k^{1,2},y_k^{1,2})\rightarrow(0,0)$ for which the limit is different and therefore nonexistent. The sequences I tried were $(x,x)$ and $(x,x^2) $ and for the first I get $\lim\limits_{(x,x)\to(0,0)}\frac{2x^3}{x^2(x-1)}=0$, and for the second one 
 $\lim\limits_{(x,x)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^4(1+x)}{x^6}=\infty$. As it's one of the first multivariable limits that I'm trying to find, I was woundering if what I did is correct, because using an online lim calculator I got that the limit is $0$.

Comment: You are correct: $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ means for any sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ tending to zero. Thus in particular the two you chose.